# Extract numbers from a string in Python without regexp

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to extract the numbers from the following text:

```
I am 25 years old and my pincode is 110092
```

above text without using the regular expression such as `\d+`.  How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you want to use regular expressions?

Comment: If you can count on a specific format of the text you can use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and take the relevant segment. I am guessing this will not be enough and avoiding `re` will be hard to support the most general case

Comment: split by whitespace, loop through and check if each item in the list is a number or not.

Comment: I have just started learning python and I want to experiment with the string methods only for now. So if you could help me with only the string method, it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So did you try to read what are the string methods and what they do and actually playing around with them? Simply getting the answer from here will not help you advance. You should come here when you have problems with actual code and we might help you figure out what's the problem with it

Answer (score 3):

Split the text by spaces and check if each fragment is a number:

```
text = 'I am 25 years old and my pincode is 110092'
numbers = [int(s) for s in text.split() if s.isdigit()]
```

Which is the short version of:

```
text = 'I am 25 years old and my pincode is 110092'
# create a list of words that are separated by spaces
split_text = text.split()
numbers = []
for fragment in split_text:
    # check if the text can be converted into a number
    if fragment.isdigit():
        # convert the string into an integer and add it to the list
        numbers.append(int(fragment))

>>> print(numbers)
[25, 110092]
```

Comment: @117223 Anyway, this is all part of basic python knowledge. You should've been able to get it just by reading, studying and experimenting with this: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#string-methods

Answer (score 0):

```
s="I am 25 years old and my pincode is 110092"
words=s.split(" ")
ints=[]
for w in words:
    try:
        ints+=[int(w)]
    except:
        pass
```

should give you what you want, but the answers written while I was drafting this one seem more pythonic

Answer (score 0):

you can use isdigit() method.
first seperate each word in string and put values in a list.
then in a for loop check every word with isdigit. if the word is digit, its return True, if not, return False.

```
text ="I am 25 years old and my pincode is 110092"
a = text.split(" ")

for i in range (len(a)):
    if (a[i].isdigit()):
        print('yes,it is digit')
```

Answer (score 0):

in case the numbers aren't delimited by spaces you could might want to check each character individually.  [`groupby` from the `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) package makes this relatively easy:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = "I am 25 years old and my pincode is 110092"

[int(''.join(gen)) for isdigits, gen in groupby(s, str.isdigit) if isdigits]
```

does the right thing, and also does the right thing if your string is:

```
s = "a23b"
```

which wouldn't work for the `split` based answers.

expanding this out a bit, we can define a function:

```
def get_grouped_digits(s):
    result = []
    for isgroupdigits, gen in groupby(s, str.isdigit):
        if isgroupdigits:
            result.append(int(''.join(gen)))
    return result
```